# Changing from Kobuki to Create base (turtlebot)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have installed the ROS groovy and I have the turtlebot 1 (with the Create base). So, in the Turtlebot tutorial, it says that the turtlebot groovy software is configured (default) to work with the Kobuki base. And I'm trying to change from the Kobuki to the Create base following the tutorial there.

The problem is, when I do these commands:

> export TURTLEBOT_BASE=create
> export TURTLEBOT_STACKS=circles
> export TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR=kinect

and when I source it in the setup.bash:

> echo "source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
> source ~/.bashrc

It doesn't seem to change anything in the turtlebot_bringup/launch/minimal.launch.
When I open minimal.launch file, it just opens like the default (turtlebot_base = kobuki, turtlebot_stacks = hexagons). And when I try to manually change, it says that I don't have permission.

So, am I doing something wrong or the file minimal.launch is not supposed to change at all?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65394/changing-from-kobuki-to-create-base-(turtlebot)/) by [kurtbra](https://answers.ros.org/users/5174/kurtbra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-06-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://answers.ros.org/question/58312/ros-groovy-and-create-based-turtlebot-dashboard/?answer=58377#post-id-58377

---

Originally posted by [airizarry8](https://answers.ros.org/users/5153/airizarry8/) with karma: 26 on 2013-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1